# Rails order active record results based on one column and another if null

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have an active record query that returns some records, lets say it looks like this.

`jobs = Job.where(:user_id => current_user.id)`

As you would expect this returns the current_user's jobs. Assume that the job has two dates, `deadline_date` and `due_date`. If I want to order on `deadline_date` I can do something like..

`jobs.order("deadline_date asc")`

That works as expected, now image I have something in the job model like this.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
 def deadline_date
  self.read_attribute(:deadline_date) || self.due_date
 end
end
```

So the job will display its `deadline_date` if it is not nil else it will fallback to use the `due_date`. So to sort this I have done the following...

```
jobs.sort_by{|job| job.deadline_date}
jobs.sort_by{|job| job.deadline_date}.reverse
```

This solves my problem but I wondered it there were better alternatives, is it possible to achieve this using SQL? Also this produces some repeated code in that I have a `sort_order` variable in my controllers that I can pass directly like this...

`jobs.order(sort_order)`

Now it looks more like this...

```
if params[:sort] == "deadline_date"
 if params[:order] == "asc"
  jobs.sort_by{|job| job.deadline_date}
 else
  jobs.sort_by{|job| job.deadline_date}.reverse
 end
else
 jobs.order(sort_order)
end
```

Note: This is a arbitrary example in reality it is a bit messy but you get the idea. So I'm looking for an SQL alternative or a suggestion on how it could be improved. Cheers

Comment: if am not wrong, basically you want to check if the sortable column is not null then sort by that column else sort by another column???

Comment: Yes I want the sorting to be based on the `deadline_date` but if that field is null then use `due_date`. The COALESCE function does the trick.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to do this using the `COALESCE` SQL function:

```
jobs.order(Arel.sql("COALESCE(deadline_date, due_date)"))
```

That's pretty much the same as `deadline_date || due_date` in Ruby.

I believe it to be a standard SQL thing, so it should work for most SQL dialects.

Comment: Just a note: From Rails 6+, this results in an error. There, it should be: 

`jobs.order(Arel.sql("COALESCE(deadline_date, due_date)"))`

Comment: Indeed, I've updated my original answer, cheers macav.