# JOIN with COALESCE and ORDER BY in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I just ran into an issue with Rails where I couldn't properly use JOIN and multiple ORDER BYs (with one of them being a COALESCE function) in the same query.  Is this something that is illegal in SQL (doubtful) or is it just an issue with Rails' implementation? Also, how can I get around it?

```
# Works!
Post.joins(:author).order("COALESCE(title, '---') DESC")
=> SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "authors" ON "posts"."author_id" = "authors"."id" ORDER BY COALESCE(title DESC, '--')

# Fails - syntax error in SQL
Post.joins(:author).order("COALESCE(title, '---') DESC").last #last should automatically apply an ORDER BY id DESC;
=> SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "authors" ON "posts"."author_id" = "authors"."id" ORDER BY COALESCE(title DESC, '--') ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: what database client you are using?

Comment: Post.joins(:author).order("COALESCE(title, '---') desc")

Comment: @ilanberci ? that's what I've written

Answer (score 4):

when applying `order("COALESCE(table.column, fallback_value) asc/desc")` to my query I started getting the following error

`ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeReference: Query method called with non-attribute argument(s):`

this was resolved by wrapping the order argument with Arel.sql as suggested by this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19660465/7573223)

`order(Arel.sql("COALESCE(table.column, fallback_value) asc/desc"))`

For more information on why this works I found this [article](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/using-arel-to-compose-sql-queries) from Thoughtbot to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `.last` applies `ASC LIMIT 1` to the SQL query.  This seems to confuse the rails syntax parser and it moves the DESC into a strange place, which causes the error.

```
SELECT "discussion_topics".* FROM "discussion_topics" ORDER BY COALESCE(title DESC, '---') ASC LIMIT 1
```

as opposed to

```
SELECT "discussion_topics".* FROM "discussion_topics" ORDER BY COALESCE(title, '---') DESC
```

You could probably change the `DESC` to an `ASC` and use `.first` safely.

Answer (score 0):

With Postgres I would try

Post.select("COALESCE(title, '---') DESC").joins(:author).order("COALESCE(title, '---') DESC").limit(1)